# Error with Declare usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare

I would like to learn how to use `declare`.

My query is like:

```
declare @iter int
set @iter = 1
```

error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@iter".

Please help!

Comment: That can't be the entire query; what's the actual query?

Comment: Select everything then run your script. If you run the declaration part and then run the set part you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done in one or two lines:

```
declare @iter int = 1
go 
-- or
declare @iter int 
set @iter = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put thw two instructions in different lines

```
declare @iter int
set @iter = 1
```

Comment: They were on two separate lines, the OP just didn't format their code properly so it looked like it was on a single line

Answer (score 0):

I execute these two line separately that's why it won't work cause before I execute set @iter = 1, SQL have cleared the declare command.